# I got this exception - The property or field 'ServerRelativeUrl' has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to upload a file generated at runtime in C# but I got below exception.

The property or field 'ServerRelativeUrl' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

I'm also using SharePoint CSOM and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
            try
            {
                ctx.Credentials = SPOCredentials;
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            catch(ClientRequestException)
            {
                ctx.Credentials = SPCredentials;
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            catch(NotSupportedException)
            {
                ctx.Credentials = SPCredentials;
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("SharePoint On-Premise");
            }

            var library = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("testtest");

            var fileBytes = new byte[] { };
            fileBytes = ReadData();

            //Information about the file
            var fileInformation = new FileCreationInformation
            {  
                //Server relative url of the document
                Url = library.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/file.pdf",
                //Overwrite file if it's already exist
                Overwrite = true,
                //Content fo the file
                Content = fileBytes
            };
            //Upload the file to root folder of the Document library
            library.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInformation);
            ctx.Load(library);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get this message is because you haven't loaded the Rootfolder.  In order to use it, put the following in:

```
var library = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("testtest");
ctx.Load(library.RootFolder);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Didn't help for some reason

Answer (score -1):

In your RootFolder class create an initialization method where you initialize the variable

```
public RootFolder()
{
    ServerRelativeUrl = string.Empty;
}
```

OR change your ServerRelativeUrl to a autoproperty

```
public string ServerRelativeUrl{set;get;}
```